# Loop de produtos do carrinho no checkout transparente do pagseguro

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Bom dia a todos,

Tenho uma duvida e um problema pra resolver. Estou montando um checkout transparente, e funciona por sinal. Atualmente coloco produtos no carrinho, somo os subtotais, para transformar em resultado total e fica perfeito, e quando eu monto array do checkout do pagseguro, informo um id, descricao e quantidade padrao, com o total calculado, e o pagamento eh realizado. A minha duvida e problema eh: como eu posso colocar os meus produtos no array do pagseguro, tendo em exemplo loop da sessao do carrinho, informando descricao, id, quantidade e valor, segue o exemplo:

```
"email=suporte@lojamodelo.com.br\
&token=57BE455F4EC148E5A54D9BB91C5AC12C\
&paymentMode=default\
&paymentMethod=creditCard\
&receiverEmail=suporte@lojamodelo.com.br\
&currency=BRL\
&extraAmount=1.00\
&itemId1=0001\ // essa linha precisa ser o loop
&itemDescription1=Produto PagSeguroI\ // essa linha precisa ser o loop
&itemAmount1=99999.99\ //essa linha precisa ser o loop
&itemQuantity1=1\ //essa linha precisa ser o loop
&itemId1=0002\
&itemDescription1=Produto PagSeguroII\
&itemAmount1=99999.98\
&itemQuantity1=2\
&notificationURL=https://sualoja.com.br/notifica.html\
&reference=REF1234\
&senderName=Jose Comprador\
&senderCPF=11475714734\
&senderAreaCode=99\
&senderPhone=99999999\
&senderEmail=comprador@uol.com.br\
&senderHash=52578d5d3336ec7a43ff1dae4794d0c5625feddcc8fbc0e80bcb0cb46c9947d4\
&shippingAddressStreet=Av. PagSeguro\
&shippingAddressNumber=9999\
&shippingAddressComplement=99o andar\
&shippingAddressDistrict=Jardim Internet\
&shippingAddressPostalCode=99999999\
&shippingAddressCity=Cidade Exemplo\
&shippingAddressState=SP\
&shippingAddressCountry=ATA\
&shippingType=1\
&shippingCost=21.50\
&creditCardToken=1e358d39e26448dc8a28d0f1815f08c5\
&installmentQuantity=1\
&installmentValue=300021.45\
&noInterestInstallmentQuantity=2\
&creditCardHolderName=Jose Comprador\
&creditCardHolderCPF=11475714734\
&creditCardHolderBirthDate=01/01/1900\
&creditCardHolderAreaCode=99\
&creditCardHolderPhone=99999999\
&billingAddressStreet=Av. PagSeguro\
&billingAddressNumber=9999\
&billingAddressComplement=99o andar\
&billingAddressDistrict=Jardim Internet\
&billingAddressPostalCode=99999999\
&billingAddressCity=Cidade Exemplo\
&billingAddressState=SP\
&billingAddressCountry=ATA".
```

Ou eu teria que colocar essas informacoes todas dentro do loop, e ter que colocar a montagem do xml, eu teria o retorno de status, duplicada varias vezes conforme quantidade de itens?

```
Tenho esse código que faz uma compra transparente do Pagseguro.
```

$params = array(
            'email'                     => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,
            'token'                     => $PAGSEGURO_TOKEN,
            'creditCardToken'           => $creditCardToken,
            'senderHash'                => $senderHash,
            'receiverEmail'             => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,
            'paymentMode'               => 'default', 
            'paymentMethod'             => 'creditCard', 
            'currency'                  => 'BRL',
            // 'extraAmount'               => '1.00',

```
        'itemId1'                   => '0001',
        'itemDescription1'          => 'PHP Test',  
        'itemAmount1'               => $numero,  
        'itemQuantity1'             => 1,

        'itemId2'                   => '0002',
        'itemDescription2'          => 'PHP Test2',  
        'itemAmount2'               => $numero,  
        'itemQuantity2'             => 1,

        'reference'                 => 'REF1234',


        'senderName'                => $senderName,
        'senderCPF'                 => $senderCPF,
        'senderAreaCode'            => 83,
        'senderPhone'               => $senderPhone,
        'senderEmail'               => $senderEmail,
        'shippingAddressStreet'     => $shippingAddressStreet,
        'shippingAddressNumber'     => $shippingAddressNumber,
        'shippingAddressDistrict'   => $shippingAddressDistrict,
        'shippingAddressPostalCode' => $shippingAddressPostalCode,
        'shippingAddressCity'       => $shippingAddressCity,
        'shippingAddressState'      => $shippingAddressState,
        'shippingAddressCountry'    => 'BRA',
        'shippingType'              => 1,
        'shippingCost'              => $shippingCost,
        'installmentQuantity'       => 1,
        'installmentValue'          => $installmentValue,
        'creditCardHolderName'      => 'Chuck Norris',
        'creditCardHolderCPF'       => '54793120652',
        'creditCardHolderBirthDate' => '01/01/1990',
        'creditCardHolderAreaCode'  => 83,
        'creditCardHolderPhone'     => '999999999',
        'billingAddressStreet'     => 'Address',
        'billingAddressNumber'     => '1234',
        'billingAddressDistrict'   => 'Bairro',
        'billingAddressPostalCode' => '58075000',
        'billingAddressCity'       => 'João Pessoa',
        'billingAddressState'      => 'PB',
        'billingAddressCountry'    => 'BRA'
    );
```

Como eu faço para o PHP pegar dinamicamente os itens do carrinho e colocar dentro do array $params[]? Para que possa ser enviados todos os produtos do carrinho?

Essa parte pega os produtos para ser gerado dentro do array pelo PHP:

```
        'itemId1'                   => '0001',
        'itemDescription1'          => 'PHP Test',  
        'itemAmount1'               => $numero,  
        'itemQuantity1'             => 1,

        'itemId2'                   => '0002',
        'itemDescription2'          => 'PHP Test2',  
        'itemAmount2'               => $numero,  
        'itemQuantity2'             => 1,
```

Ficaria assim?

$params = array(

```
    'email'                     => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,  
    'token'                     => $PAGSEGURO_TOKEN,
    'creditCardToken'           => $creditCardToken,
    'senderHash'                => $senderHash,
    'receiverEmail'             => $PAGSEGURO_EMAIL,
    'paymentMode'               => 'default', 
    'paymentMethod'             => 'creditCard', 
    'currency'                  => 'BRL',
    // 'extraAmount'               => '1.00',

    'reference'                 => 'REF1234',    

    'senderName'                => $senderName,
    'senderCPF'                 => $senderCPF,
    'senderAreaCode'            => 83,
    'senderPhone'               => $senderPhone,
    'senderEmail'               => $senderEmail,
    'shippingAddressStreet'     => $shippingAddressStreet,
    'shippingAddressNumber'     => $shippingAddressNumber,
    'shippingAddressDistrict'   => $shippingAddressDistrict,
    'shippingAddressPostalCode' => $shippingAddressPostalCode,
    'shippingAddressCity'       => $shippingAddressCity,
    'shippingAddressState'      => $shippingAddressState,
    'shippingAddressCountry'    => 'BRA',
    'shippingType'              => 1,
    'shippingCost'              => '1.00',
    'installmentQuantity'       => 1,
    'installmentValue'          => '3.00',
    'creditCardHolderName'      => 'Chuck Norris',
    'creditCardHolderCPF'       => '54793120652',
    'creditCardHolderBirthDate' => '01/01/1990',
    'creditCardHolderAreaCode'  => 83,
    'creditCardHolderPhone'     => '999999999',
    'billingAddressStreet'     => 'Address',
    'billingAddressNumber'     => '1234',
    'billingAddressDistrict'   => 'Bairro',
    'billingAddressPostalCode' => '58075000',
    'billingAddressCity'       => 'João Pessoa',
    'billingAddressState'      => 'PB',
    'billingAddressCountry'    => 'BRA'
);
```

$filter = preg_grep('/^itemId([0-9]{1,})/', array_keys( $params ));
    $result = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($filter); $i++)
    {

```
    $result['itemId' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemId' . ($i + 1)];
    $result['itemDescription' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemDescription' . ($i + 1)];
    $result['itemAmount' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemAmount' . ($i + 1)];
    $result['itemQuantity' . ($i + 1)] = $params['itemQuantity' . ($i + 1)];

}


$header = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=UTF-8;');
$response = curlExec($PAGSEGURO_API_URL."/transactions", $params, $header);
$json = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)));
```

?>